# Is there a way to use find to filter a file list?

Tags: bash, find, locate

I have the output of `locate --existing --regex` that was quite fast to obtain. A similar `find` takes several hours - it's a huge volume.

I would like to apply further `find` filters to this file list.

The only shortcut I've found is to apply the same search twice: first get a list of directories with those files using `locate`, then run it via a nonrecursive `find`:

```
# Abandoned Office temporary files
PATTERN='/foo/.+/~$[^/]+'

# locate doesn't re-enter the same path so sort before uniq is unnecessary.
# --existing is unnecessary, since locality of reference and thus
# performance and load are better when stat-ing the entries is done only
# once by `find`
locate --regex "$PATTERN" | xargs -d\\n -L1 dirname -- | uniq | \
  while read -r path; do
    find "$path" -maxdepth 0 -regex "$PATTERN" -type f -ctime +30 -exec rm '{}' ';'
  done
```

Is there a less convoluted way of doing it?

Comment: Are the resulting patterns sometimes *directories*, or always files?

Comment: I don't care about the directories - thus `find ... -type f`. On my system the output of `locate` returns very few non-files (there's a few `.mappedfiles` folders that had entries starting with `~`).